# Resolution Resets After Every Reboot

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, xubuntu, resolution, reset

I know this question has been asked before, and I know I've fixed this before, but I can't find anything that works for some reason.

Background: Every time I log in, my resolution resets to 1024x768, so I have to open up the nvidia settings and change it back to 1280x1024 every time.

Question: Is there a fix for this issue?

Additional Info:

- Dell XPS 400
- Xubuntu 12.10 (fresh install, not upgraded from 12.04)
- Graphics Card: Nvidia GT430
- GPU Driver: nvidia-current-updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I think I was hitting was that the Nvidia x-server would load my preferred resolution (1280x1024), but then the settings manager would load *its* preferred option, which by default was 1024x768.

How I ended up solving this - in terminal:

- `sudo leafpad /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Scroll down, likely near or at the bottom, to where it says something like:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "1280x1024_75 +0+0; nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The third option ("metamodes") is the resolution option. In that line, I removed the `; nvidia-auto-select +0+0`. The line now looked like this:

```
Option         "metamodes" "1280x1024_75 +0+0"
```

This disallowed the settings manager to select the resolution it wanted and override xorg.conf, thus forcing the computer to use 1280x1024 by default.

Answer (score 1):

[image: nvidia-settings]

In nvidia-settings, under `X Server Display Configuration`, click `Save to X Configuration File`.  If you've never done this before, it will complain about not being able to parse /etc/X11/xorg.conf.  Just tell it "OK", it doesn't matter.  You'll need to give it your password to elevate so that it can write to that file.  Once you've done this, your resolution (and other changes in nvidia-settings) will persist through reboots.

Comment: I thought I had tried that before but just to be sure, I deleted the old xorg.conf, applied my settings, then saved a new one. This, unfortunately, didn't work. I feel weird doing this, but I'm answering the question myself since I figured out how to do it, and accepting it tomorrow.

Thanks for responding!

Comment: Nothing weird about that at all @DaimyoKirby, it was helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

My setting were going from `1200x790` to a default of `640x480`.

[Here](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/531205/nvidia-surround-problems/)'s the solution I found.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The thread you linked is a bit long. Could you edit your answer and provide the *specific* steps that you took to resolve the issue and using the link only as a reference?