# How can I improve my screen resolution?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, resolution

I followed the solution suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221868/resolution-resets-after-every-reboot) but making those changes in my xorg.conf file didn't help. When I restart my computer, I still have a resolution of 1280x1024 even though my native resolution is 1440x900. I have re-installed drivers a couple of times, but still nothing.

```
Nvidia drivers version:
Operating System: Linux-x86
NVIDIA Driver Version: 304.64
Server Version Number: 11.0
Screens: 1
```

Ubuntu 12.10 (32bit)

Answer (score 1):

When you go to software updates, click settings then the drives tap, if there are more then 1 option, choose the one you prefer, preferably the one with Nvidia or AMD